# Errors when trying to update NuGet packages

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

When I try to update the NuGet packages for my solution, I get a set of errors as follows and however methods I tried, did not resolve the problem. Can someone please explain me and help me resolve this problem? Thank you in advance.

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @daramasala said in the reply, "latest version of the support library is 25.3.1  which is Android 7". In my project, the **Target Android Version** was already set to 7, but then I set the **Compile using Android version** to Android 7 as well, and after that, I could update the NuGet packages without an issue.

You can set the **Target Android Version**, **Compile using Android version** as well as the **Minimum Android version** by going to project **Properties** from the **Application** section....

[image: Screenshot of the properties window]

Answer (score 2):

The error message explains the problem. The latest version of the support library is 25.3.1 which is Android 7. Your project targets Android 6. So either change your project's target (in Project Options|General|Target framework) to 7 (or 7.1) or use version 23 of the support library.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However, it wasn't the Target version that was the issue, because it was already set to 7. I had set the compile version to 6 and changing it to 7 solved the issue. :)